# Cancel form closing

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I'm writing a WinForm desktop application. In the main form, the user clicks on a button which calls another form for the user to submit data to. At the end of this submission process, the user clicks on a "Save" menu item to close the subform.

This is the code for the subform calling:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code for setting myFormArgs

    myForm form = new myForm(myFormArgs);
    form.ShowDialog();

    // the user clicked "Yes" on a "Confirm" MessageBox
    if (form.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // code for saving data 

        form.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and this is the code for the "Save" menu item in the subform:

```
private void menuSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message, title;
    MessageBoxIcon icon;
    MessageBoxButtons buttons;

    if(DataSubmitted)
    {
        if(ValidData)
        {
            message = "Confirm?";
            title = "Select an action";
            icon = MessageBoxIcon.Information;
            buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Incomplete data";
            title = "Error";
            icon = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
            buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        message = "No data submitted";
        title = "Error";
        icon = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
        buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
    }
    this.DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(message, title, buttons, icon);
    if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes) this.Close();
    else this.OnFormClosing(new FormClosingEventArgs(CloseReason.None, true));
}
```

The problem is that the code will always get back to the calling method, thus closing (maybe just hiding?) the sub-form, even if the `this.Close()` method isn't called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Setting a modal form's DialogResult property to anything other than None will close the form.  You don't have to call `form.Dispose();` when the form is closing.  It would be better to put your form in a using block instead.

Comment: The call to this.OnFormClosing() is mysterious.  Surely you meant for the dialog to stay on the screen, so calling it doesn't make sense.  And don't trap the user, you have to give him a way to get out of the dialog without finishing it.  "Incomplete data" is not an error.  Dialogs should always have an OK and Cancel button.

Comment: @HansPassant that call was a (failing) try at prevent the form from closing. Incomplete data IS an error when the user is already given a way out, especially when clicking on a “Save” button.

Comment: Close a dialog by setting the DialogResult property.  The OK button can do validation and reset DialogResult back to None if you are unhappy.

Comment: @LarsTech setting DialogResult to None made it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it strange that you want to close the form when the user just wants to save the data. :)

Save should not close your form.

When you close the form, you should verify if there are unsaved changes.
If there are, ask the user the question if he wants to save his changes before closing and offer him the options Yes, No and Cancel, where Cancel means 'cancel closing the form'.

Depending on wether the user clicked Yes or No, you should or shouldn't save the changes.
If the user clicked cancel, you should cancel closing the form by having an event for the FormClosing event.   This event allows you to cancel closing the form.

```
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (unsavedChanges)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Save changes?", "unsaved changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                SaveChanges();
            }
            if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                cancelClose = true;
            }
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = cancelClose;
        cancelClose = false;
    }
```

The code above is usefull when 'Form2' is not a modal form.

If you want Form2 to be shown modal, the code above will work as well.  However, you can also use the DialogResult proprety of the Form in that case:

```
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (unsavedChanges)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Save changes?", "unsaved changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                SaveChanges();
            }

            if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                result = DialogResult.None;
            }

            this.DialogResult = result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not make a new event instance, those are things you would want to avoid
 instead try:

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Sure", "Some Title", 
MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Close();
}
```

Events are supposed to occur automatically, so 'OnFormClosing' will raise when the form will close.

also i recommend to use this.Close instead of Dispose 
Form.Close() sends the proper Windows messages to shut down the win32 window. During that process, if the form was not shown modally, Dispose is called on the form. Disposing the form frees up the unmanaged resources that the form is holding onto.

for more organized code,
try making an instance of the form from the main form
and handle the dialog result like this:

```
using (SubForm form = new SubForm())
{
     DialogResult dr = form.ShowDialog();
         if(dr == DialogResult.Yes)
         {
             string studdToSave= form.StuffToSave;
             SaveToFile(studdToSave);
         }

}
```